# Having trouble following the logic of this proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm confused about

1. The highlighted portion
2. The logic of the proof thereafter. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Everyone here hates image links.  Take the time to typeset your question correctly, **together with** your efforts and understanding of the problem, and you'll help people to help you. It's also good to have an actual question.

Comment: Thanks, will do.

Comment: People here are crazy helpful if the poster shows effort.  It's great.

Comment: Also, if you have two separate questions, make them two separate posts.

Comment: There is a typo in the original. The numerator in the second line of the displayed formula should be $|5x^2+6x+12|$.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why we could choose a bound of $\mid x - 2\mid$ is that the limit is a local feature. We could only consider the case where $x$ is near $2$. 
How we choose $\delta$ here is simple to consider the restriction that we mentioned earlier and to make sure the difference is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: I'm not understanding your logic - they obtained abs(x-2) from what appears to be a simplification of the lhs numerator. I'm still confused as to how they did that simplication and the intution behind "to get an upper bound, we restrict ... "

Comment: @quantactuary It is separating $\mid x-2 \mid$ so it could bound the coefficient of this term. Since we only need to consider where $x$ near 2, we could bound the coefficient by an interval containing 2. So it is easier to find a $\delta$ that works.